# Just wanted to know is the below code is wrong or it will work for ranking schema?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

```
itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"
```

Though I know the correct syntax is

```
itemscope itemtype ="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"
```

But wanted to know can we write

```
itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating""
```

Because Google structure validation tool is not showing any erros and even Google webmasters tools is not showing any errors.

Comment: It’s hard to understand what your actual question is. What do you want to achieve? What markup do you have, and what is the problem?

Comment: I have put the aggregate ranking schema 3-4 months before to my website, but still its not showing in Google search when search it with a query. But when I search with the site operator it is visible to me. I thought may be the syntax is wrong but I have rectified that one. So, the problem is why the schema is not showing in Google search results with a search query??

Comment: So that would be a different question, and it would be more suitable for [webmasters.se] -- they already seem to have a question about the same issue: [Why did Google stop showing our reviews rich snippets data?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/86408/17633)